# Using css media queries to re-arrange elements

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm a relative novice with CSS. I have a header bar on my site that looks like this:
[image]

I'm using media queries to adjust it for narrow displays. I've got the menu bar to compact into a single dropdown and shrunk the logo, but I want to re-order the elements so they look like this:
[image]

I can't find a way to make this work - I need to contain the title and menu bar within a div to group them together in the first version, which means I can't arrange them as shown in the second version.

Is there a system of divs that can produce the top layout and the bottom layout, changing only the CSS and not the HTML?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Can you post your code as a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this easily with CSS grids. In the snippet below, if you press `Expand snippet` you will see the full version.

I wasn't sure if the "shrunk menu" should be off grid like your graphic, but in case it's not needed, you just need to remove the `width` property on the media query.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 270px;
  grid-template-rows: 57px 32px;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "logo header"
    "logo menu";
}

.wrapper > div {
  outline: 4px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 83px 213px;
    grid-template-rows: 57px 32px;
    grid-gap: 14px 9px;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "logo header"
      "menu .";
  }
  .menu {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="header">Page Title/header</div>
  <div class="menu">Menu Bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thankyou. I hadn't encountered grid before. It's strange that grid and flex don't seem to be as well covered in online resources as other layout methods, yet they're both far more intuative and useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution to solve the same problem using CSS.

CSS and HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1, ul, li {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        li {
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        .logo {
            width:50px;
            height:55px;
        }
        h1.heading, nav {
            margin-left:0.5em;
        }
        h1.heading, .logo, nav {
            border:2px solid #000;
        }
        .left {
            float:left;
        }
        nav {
            margin-top:0.25em;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:414px) {
            section.left {
                float:none;
            }
            h1 {
                float:left;
            }
            nav {
                clear:both;
                float:left;
                margin-left:0;
           }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="logo left"></div>
        <section class="left">
            <h1 class="heading">Page Title</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>link 1</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```